# Cannot open any child page on site

Tags: templates, multi-site-manager, children, child

I cannot open any child page generated by EE in 2 of my 3 sites which use Multiple Site Manager. Only my 'home site,' which contains all the EE system files, can open child pages. I have them listed below for reference:

Site 1, can open child pages: http://beta.autouplinktech.com (home site)
Site 2, cannot open child pages: http://dev.autouplinkusa.com
Site 3, cannot open child pages: http://dev.customerlifecycle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem with your .htaccess rule for removing index.php.

If I access this company page with index.php it works just fine: http://dev.autouplinkusa.com/index.php/company

Do you have .htaccess file in place for all three sites?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227820/htaccess-on-expressionengine-msm-site

Comment: Issue was with the Mod_Rewrite in the htaccess file for each site, in fact the file wasn't even present in the two sites where I had the issue. The htaccess file was copied from the working site to the non-functional sites and all seemed to work okay.